# How do I change this Hibernate code with org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions code to JPA. Is there any alternatives to Restrictions API?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, migration, hibernate-restrictions

Does anyone know how to change this to JPA? and if there are any alternatives for the org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions API? Thank you!

```
public void initShowAFilterCriteria (Criteria crit, ShowingAFilter filter, Object user) {

    if(filter == null) {
        return; // do nothing
    }
    switch (filter) {
        case ALL;
            break; // do nothing
        case MINE;
            crit.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.isNull("something"),
                    Restrictions.eq("something.id", user.getId())));
            crit.add(Restrictions.eq(Object.A_CONSTANT, "N"));
            break;
            /**
             * the rest of the switch statments are in a similar construct
             */
            
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CriteriaBuilder` and `CriteriaQuery` interface instead of Hibernate's `Restrictions` and `Criteria`, just like follows:

```
public CriteriaQuery<User> initShowAFilterCriteria (CriteriaBuilder cb, ShowingAFilter filter, Object user) {

    CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

    if(filter == null) {
        return; // do nothing
    }
    switch (filter) {
        case ALL;
            break; // do nothing
        case MINE;
            cq.select(root)
                .where(cb.or(
                    cb.isNotNull(root.get("something")), 
                    cb.equal(root.get("something.id"), user.getId())))
                .where(cb.equal(root.get(Object.A_CONSTANT), "N"));
            break;
            /**
             * the rest of the switch statments are in a similar construct
             */
    }
    return cq;
}
```

> Attention: Unlike Hibernate’s `Criteria` can perform a query directly, using JPA's API, you need return a `CriteriaQuery` instance to do that.

Comment: Thank you Desmond, but what if I already declared those variables outside the method initShowingFilterCriteria() and this method just built on it. For example:

Comment: What do you mean *those variables*?

Comment: I mean't what if this line of code had already been declared outside the method: CriteriaQuery<User> cq = cb.createQuery(User.class);
    Root<User> root = cq.from(User.class);

Comment: You just need to pass those variables(`cb`, `cq`, `root`) as arguments of the method initShowingFilterCriteria.